# Building Codeigniter URLs with variable segments

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I have searched for the solution to my problem in CI user guide and on Stackoverflow as well but couldn't find.  So, here is my problem.

I need to build SEO friendly URLs.  I have a controller called "Outlets" and the view that I need to generate will have a URL structure like http://www.mysite.com/[city]/[area]/[outlet-name].

The segments city and area are fields in their respective tables and outlet_name is a field in the table "Outlets".

I am able to generate a URL like http://www.mysite.com/outlets/123 but how do I add the city and area name to the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your page use the same controller, in config/routes.php add this...

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "outlets/$1/$2/$3";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "outlets/$1/$2/$3/$4"; // fixed typo
```

In the controller you will want to remap the function calls because Codeigniter will be looking for functions with the names of the city and they will not exist.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

```
public function _remap($city, $area, $outlet, $options = '')
{
  $this->some_function_below($city, $area, $outlet, $options);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I have more than one controller.  Also, what if I need to pass additional segments to the URL, for example, http://www.mysite.com/[city]/[area]/[outlet-name]/[outlet-pictures]/123.  Should I simply add two more parameters to the routing rule.

Comment: You can either use the routes to pass the variables or you can test for them in the controller. I edited answer above to show passing more options. The URL will remain (mysite.com/[city]/[area]/[outlet-name]/[outlet-pictures]/123) so in the controller you can still test for segment 4 and 5. In your remap function you can call different functions based on your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution.

You can use URI segments. For an url like http://www.mysite.com/[city]/[area]/[outlet-name]

```
<?php

$this->uri->segment(3);  // city
$this->uri->segment(4);  // area
$this->uri->segment(5);  // outlet-name

?>
```

and so on... See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html for more details.

Comment: My understanding is that $this->uri->segment() is used to retrieve segments of URLs.  The problem that I am facing is not related to retrieving URL segments but setting up segments for loading a view.  To clarify again, I want to build a URL like http://www.mysite.com/[city]/[area]/[outlet-name] that should load the outlet details view at http://www.mysite.com/outlets/123.  The problem is how to pass the city and area name to the URL.  It seems I need help with reverse routing.